# running SALOME in windows 10 gives "Can't find a free port" error

Tags: cad

I'm trying to run SALOME GUI using run_salome.bat. GUI doesn't start and gives "Can't find a free port to launch omniNamesTry to kill the running servers and then launch SALOME again." error.

SALOME version 9.4
Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

I have searched the files in C:\Users<username>\AppData\Roaming that contain "omniORB_PortManager" in their name and deleted them.

Answer (score 0):

Here the issue can be resolved be removing several files generated by SALOME.

- start a Windows file browser
- in the search bar, type: `%userprofile%\.config\salome`
- delete all files present in that directory
- in the search bar, type: `%APPDATA%\salome`
- remove all files present in that directory
- in the search bar, type: `%APPDATA%`
- delete all files wich name starts with: `.omni`
- delete file: `.salome_PortManager.cfg`

Finally, I strongly suggest to raise such questions directly on SALOME forum at this [link](https://discourse.salome-platform.org/)